# SoapFault exception: [soapenv:Client] Only one operation within the same request is allowed

Tags: php, wordpress, wsdl, salesforce, integration

We're exposing an `Apex WDSL` in a **Wordpress** platform to call an update method in the Apex WSDL through PHP. The update method will accept lead id and array of fields. However, the call is raising the following error:

> SoapFault exception: [soapenv:Client] Only one operation within the
>   same request is allowed.

Is this an error in Salesforce or error in Wordpress/PHP ?

Comment: Could you add the code you used please?

Answer (score 0):

When your Web service generates the xml file or you follow code first approach then,

```
    <binding name="**************" type="tns:*********">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
        <operation name="*******">
            <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
...............
......
</ closing all the tags ...>
```

Make sure there is only single `<soap:operation soapAction=""/>` used according to the hierarchy mentioned above.